# Using a iPhone 5 as a bluetooth receiver/audio sink

Tags: iphone, audio, bluetooth

Imagine this: you are in a hotel on a holiday trip and want to see something on TV, but your partner doesn't like it and prefers reading a book. There are a lot of small devices you could plug in the TV to transmit the sound via bluetooth, but i don't want to take a bluetooth headset on vacation when i already have my iPhone with me (including earphones).

Is there an app that allows me to use a iPhone as a bluetooth receiver, so i can listen to the audio transmitted by the TV (via the bluetooth adapter)?

If there is no app, could there be one, e.g. does the iPhone SDK permits receiving audio via bluetooth?

Comment: if you plug in a BT in to the TV cant you pair with it ? most hotels I was at do not have TV with USB plug anyway, so just get an extension cable for your earphones.

Comment: Most Bluetooth Stereo Transmitters (like the TaoTronics TT-BA01) use the analog 3,5mm audio output or the  2 RCA analog output as a input, not USB, so they work with pretty any TV set imaginable.

Comment: I guess I should go out more often to learn what new stuff is out there :)

Answer (score 1):

I have the same question (but PC -> iPhone)

Here is a bit more information to help, connecting iPhone -> PC you are able to have an audio sink service on the PC where all sounds from the phone will play through the computer speakers but not where the phone is the sink (receiver)

If you connect a laptop to a PC you are able to have either as the sink (receiver).

**Answer:**

As far as I am aware Apple has blocked the Bluetooth Audio Sink Service on (at min) the iPhone (4S IOS7)